# ASP.Net core Blazor data binding broke

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, blazor-server-side

Somehow over the course of the past 2 days my data binding to a model has broken on my pages used to "add new" and "update" database records.  I have the below code - I minimized it for view purposes.

```
@page "/NewRepairOrder"
@using ShopLiveWebVersion2._0.Models
@using ShopLiveWebVersion2._0.DataAccess
@using ShopLiveWebVersion2._0.Services
@using ShopLiveWebVersion2._0.Data
@inject IUriHelper UriHelper
@inject RepairOrderContext context

    <div class="container">
        @if (RO == null)
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6 float-right">
                    <h2>Loading....</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <h2>Add New Repair Order</h2>
                    <h4>@ErrorMessage</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    <label for="ControlNumber" class="Control-label">Repair Order #:"</label>
                    <input for="ControlNumber" class="form-control" bind="@RO.ControlNumber" maxlength="15" required />
                </div>
```

The HTML of the page continues to include other input and selection box's. Below is the entire Functions block of code.

```
@functions
{
    private OptionsDataAccess OpsData;
    private RepairOrderDataAccess ROData;

    private List<LocationOptions> LocationOps;
    private List<EmployeeOptions> EmployeeOps;
    private List<StatusOptions> StatusOps;

    private RepairOrder RO = new RepairOrder();
    private string ErrorMessage;


    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        LocationOps = new List<LocationOptions>();
        EmployeeOps = new List<EmployeeOptions>();
        StatusOps = new List<StatusOptions>();

        OpsData = new OptionsDataAccess(context);
        ROData = new RepairOrderDataAccess(context);

        LocationOps = await Task.Run(() => OpsData.GetAllLocationOptions());
        EmployeeOps = await Task.Run(() => OpsData.GetAllEmployeeOptions());
        StatusOps = await Task.Run(() => OpsData.GetAllStatusOptions());

    }

    private void SaveRepairOrder()
    {

        try
        {
            ROData.AddRepairOrder(RO);
            //UriHelper.NavigateTo("/Home");
        }
        catch
        {
            ErrorMessage = "Could not Save the Data -- try again";
        }

    }
}
```

I originally had the "RO = new RepairOrder();" in the InitAsync() method while the declaration was outside.  Throwing spit balls I included it as a one liner outside of the method.

When I click the save button, an RO with all NULL values is stored in the database.

I added label elements to the bottom of the page bound to the same data as the input and select to see the effect before closing the page, and they show NULL as well.

I also attempted to create separate string items for each and then right before the RO is sent to the database do "RO.  = {item};".

Has anyone seen binding be disabled like this??

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer for this is to make sure you read the changes to whatever you are updating.  The newest update has some crucial breaking changes.  The one that got me was data binding.

I had to change all my code from:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
      <label for="ControlNumber" class="Control-label">Repair Order #:"</label>
      <input for="ControlNumber" class="form-control" bind="@RO.ControlNumber" maxlength="15" required />
</div>
```

to the new way of data binding:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
      <label for="ControlNumber" class="Control-label">Repair Order #:"</label>
      <input for="ControlNumber" class="form-control" @bind="RO.ControlNumber" maxlength="15" required />
</div>
```

For binding elements to a method in your "functions" or "code" (now called) you use a slightly different format.

```
<button class="btn" @onclick="@DoSomthing">Click Me</button>
```

I will note that the new style data binding did kill my intellisense within an object. intellisense would show the object name but once you hit "enter" or selected the object none of the internal items popped up in intellisense.

The biggest lesson I relearned today - ALWAYS READ THE CHANGE DOCUMENTS!